# Inspect MetaSearch columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchlogic, meta-search

Regarding [MetaSearch](https://github.com/ernie/meta_search), I would like to extract "human" names from the search parameters.  For example, when the params[:search] has non-blank values for the following:

```
- title_contains

- author_name_contains
```

I would like to extract:

```
- title

- author name
```

The end use would be to provide additional feedback to the user such as:

```
Results filtered on title and author name
```

I would **like to use functions within the MetaSearch library** to achieve this instead of re-developing the param parsing.  While the above examples are simple in Ruby the MetaSearch parameter language can be expressive.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get these from the MetaSearch object, you can do something like:

```
@search.search_attributes.except('meta_sort').select {|k, v| v.present?}
```

I'm not really sure that you're gaining anything over pulling this from the params directly, though. In any real-world usage, you'd probably want to change the text you display based on the predicate.

You may want to tackle this using i18n, instead:

http://rdoc.info/github/ernie/meta_search/master/file/README.rdoc#Localization

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use i18n to tackle this.

Comment: To humanize the parameters I used @search.class.human_attribute_name(k)